# Safari issue with grid animation

Tags: css, sass

I found this animated 80s grid. It work fines on Chrome and Firefox but issue is with Safari.

On Safari Grid lines pop out when animations is running, they are not behind the `ellipse` shadow.
https://codepen.io/TonyBaldascino/pen/kXjGLk

```css
body {
  background-color: #0e1416;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  perspective: 450px;
}

.grid-fade {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at 50% 50%, rgba(14, 20, 22, 0) 0%, #0e1416 80%);
}

.grid-lines {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(7, 203, 121, 0.3) 1px, transparent 0),
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(7, 203, 121, 0.3) 1px, transparent 0);
  background-size: 45px 30px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  transform-origin: 100% 0 0;
  animation: play 15s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes play {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(45deg) translateY(-50%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(45deg) translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="grid-fade"></div>
        <div class="grid-lines"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Picture from my experimentation but same is happening from the author. 
Left is Chrome, Right is Safari, and on Safari the grid lines extend all the way to the edge but i like how it looks on Chrome, or at-least that is what is intended on Chrome.

[image]

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) to any third party site.

Comment: But isin't it easier to check on codepen with a working example than plane code?

Comment: You can create the same thing here with code snippets.

Comment: [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Done it, never tried this snippets before :) something i will keep in mind.